# What is the laser sound in the tunnel?

Tags: james-bond, sound-effects, dr-no

In Dr. No when James Bond escapes his cell (through the electric fence) he is in a tunnel, climbing down, when suddenly there's what sounds like a laser (it sounded like a Sonar signal)

He looks up, but there's nothing there.

What is the noise exactly, and what caused it?

Comment: If you are an adventurous type, find an abandoned factory in your area, sneak into it with a friend, find a length of ductwork (air conditioning or the like), stand at one end, and have your friend tap on the other end with a hammer or piece of lumber and listen.

Answer (score 2):

Those sounds appear to be pipe experiencing [thermal expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_expansion) as well as the noises of the coolant valves opening and closing.

You may wish to note that the pipe is becoming uncomfortably hot (forcing James to fashion himself cloth mittens), then shortly after the metallic "[ping](http://www.deseretnews.com/article/588099/Heating-ducts-make-popping-noise.html?pg=all)" is heard, a wave of water comes rushing through the tunnel and nearly washes poor Mr Bond away. We then see water boiling and steaming on the metal walls of the tunnel.